# Rails3: Rendering from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting started with rails, so this is a fairly basic question.  I am trying to render a login form (authlogic) in the homepage, using this code:

views/home/index.html.haml:

```
%p
  This is the home page...!

- if current_user
- else
  = render :template => 'user_sessions/new'
```

user_sessions_controller:

```
class UserSessionsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_no_user, :only => [:new, :create]
  before_filter :require_user, :only => :destroy

  def new
    @user_session = UserSession.new
  end

  def create
    @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
    if @user_session.save
      flash[:notice] = "Login successful!"
      redirect_back_or_default user_controls_url
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end

  def destroy
    current_user_session.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Logout successful!"
    redirect_back_or_default home_url
  end
end
```

views/user_sessions/new.html.haml

```
= form_for @user_session, :url => {:action => "create"} do |f|
  = f.error_messages
  %div
    = f.label :login
    = f.text_field :login
  %div
    = f.label :password
    = f.password_field :password
  %div
    = f.check_box :remember_me
    = f.label :remember_me
  %div
    = f.submit "Login"
```

models/user_session.rb

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base

  def to_key
    new_record? ? nil : [ self.send(self.class.primary_key) ]
  end

  httponly true
  secure true
end
```

When I visit the homepage, I get:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class):
1: = form_for @user_session, :url => {:action => "create"} do |f|
2:   = f.error_messages
3:   %div
4:     = f.label :login
  app/views/user_sessions/new.html.haml:1:in `_app_views_user_sessions_new_html_haml___182031841_97682750'
  app/views/home/index.html.haml:6:in `_app_views_home_index_html_haml__679857083_97787190'
```

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `@user_session` is being created when you visit the `new` action that is connected to `user_sessions/new`; it is not created when you go to the `index` action.

When you render the `user_sessions/new` template from the `index` action, ERB/HAML is looking for an instance of `@user_session` and cannot find it, hence the error.

So, you could instantiate `@user_session` like this:

```
#Note: The <%%> is ERB code (please adjust it for the syntax used in HAML)
<% @user_session = UserSession.new if @user_session.nil? %>

= form_for @user_session, :url => {:action => "create"} do |f|
...
```

Or, you can also do it in the `index` action itself, though it would be better to keep it out from the `index` action and instead do it as above (eg. what if you want to render the template from some other action as well - then you would be duplicating code unnecessarily)

Comment: I had tried this before, but was obviously doing something wrong.  Now it works!  Thanks a lot!!